# Reading text from file and storing each word from every line into separate variables

Tags: java, file-io

I have a .txt file with the following content:

```
1 1111 47
2 2222 92
3 3333 81
```

I would like to read line-by-line and store each word into different variables.

For example: When I read the first line "1 1111 47", I would like store the first word "1" into `var_1`, "1111" into `var_2`, and "47" into `var_3`. Then, when it goes to the next line, the values should be stored into the same `var_1`, `var_2` and `var_3` variables respectively.

My initial approach is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
class ReadFromFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin;
        try
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fex)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            return;
        }
        do 
        {
            i = fin.read();
            if(i != -1) 
                System.out.print((char) i);
        } while(i != -1);

        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Kindly give me your suggestions. Thank You

Comment: `String[] vars=i.split(" ");var_1=vars[0];var_2=vars[1];var_3=vars[2];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/path/to/InputFile");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    String line = null;
    while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
        // \\s+ means any number of whitespaces between tokens
        String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String var_1 = tokens[0];
        String var_2 = tokens[1];
        String var_3 = tokens[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you checking here   while( !(line = br.readLine()).equals(""))

Comment: @SantoshVM checking if another line really exists. line=br.readLine() will return null if there are no other lines. So I am checking it againt != null. If it is true means this is indeed a line, thus do the work

Comment: is there any way of doing this parsing without using the BufferedReader function?

Comment: @SantoshVM I guess so, but it is going to be harder, you will do to manually determine where a new line starts in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ASCII"));
        while(true)
        {
            String line = fr.readLine();
            if(line==null)
                break;
            String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for reading lines. You'll have to explode the line afterwards using something like [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or String's split.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File f = new File("main.txt");
        StringBuffer txt = new StringBuffer();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            txt.append(args[i] + " ");
        }
        fos.write(txt.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("main.txt");
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
        String data;
        String result = new String();
        StringBuffer txt1 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer txt2 = new StringBuffer();
        File f1 = new File("even.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(f1);
        File f2 = new File("odd.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result.concat(data);
            String[] words = data.split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(words[j]);
                    txt1.append(words[j] + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(words[j]);
                    txt2.append(words[j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        fos1.write(txt1.toString().getBytes());
        fos1.close();
        fos2.write(txt2.toString().getBytes());
        fos2.close();
        br.close();

    }
}
```